# Taking values from a character list and duplicating/repeating them

Tags: r, string

I have a list of characters, and I want to return the list in a way which takes each value and then duplicates it, with a hyphen separating it. For example:

```
"12", "34", "56", "78"
```

would become

```
"12-12", "34-34", "56-56", "78-78"
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Try `paste` or `paste0`: `x <- c("12", "34", "56", "78"); paste(x, x, sep = '-')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are approaches that can create the same string more that 2 times without typing, for example, `paste(x, x, x, ..., sep = "-")`. We can define a function using `rep` and `paste`, and then use `sapply` to loop through the vector. `vec2` is the final output.

```
# Create example vector
vec1 <- c("12", "34", "56", "78")

# Design a function to repeat a string and concatenate by "-"
conc_fun <- function(string, times = 2){
  # The argument "times" allows the users to specify how many times to repeat 
  temp_vec <- rep(string, each = times)
  temp_string <- paste(temp_vec, collapse = "-")
  return(temp_string)
}

# Apply the conc_fun to vec1
vec2 <- sapply(vec1, conc_fun)
```

Or we can create a `matrix` with the same contents, and then use `apply` and `paste`.

```
vec2 <- apply(matrix(rep(vec1, 2), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE), 2, paste, collapse = "-")
```

#### Benchmarking

Once the `conc_fun` function is defined, there are no significant differences between the first method (using `sapply`) and the second method (using `matrix` and `apply`) in terms of performance. To me, both of them are valid.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  m1 = {vec2 <- sapply(vec1, conc_fun)},
  m2 = {vec2 <- apply(matrix(rep(vec1, 2), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE), 2, paste, collapse = "-")}
)

Unit: microseconds
 expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval
   m1 28.867 30.150 35.57701 31.433 35.6025 119.958   100
   m2 30.150 32.075 41.57487 33.358 42.0175 147.541   100
```

Comment: `paste` is vectorised

Comment: @HongOoi I know, but how to avoid concatenating numbers that are not the same?

Comment: @HongOoi For example, this `paste(rep(vec1, each = 2), collapse = "-")` creates a long string with all numbers concatenated together.

Comment: @HongOoi I think I found a way. Please see my update.